# ssl negotiation happens multiple times for same domain

Tags: ssl

I've done a speedtest with webpagetest. My website is SSL secured. For some reason the SSL Negotiation happens twice.

[image]

There is one SSL negotiation for the index html which seems to be correct. The second request is done by fetch. I assume that the second SSL negotiation is not neccessary.

```
fetch("/api/menu")
```

For the remaining requests to the same domain there are no more negotiations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is first a TCP connect for `menu` which is then followed by the SSL setup. This means that it is not using the previously established TCP connection for the new connection but creates a new one. And this new one of course needs SSL too.

It is quite normal that browsers have several connections open to the same site when HTTP/1.1 is in use since only a single request can be handled at a time within one connection (this is different with HTTP/2). Since in your case the first connection is still in use for other requests, creating a new connection might speed up the total delivery time.

It can also be seen that the second SSL setup takes less time than the first. This is probably because it is doing a session resume, i.e. using the same SSL session as established in the first connection which speeds up the TLS handshake.